# Difference Between Cloud Data fusion and DataFlow on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-data-fusion

What is the difference between GCP pipeline services:
Cloud Dataflow and Cloud Data fusion ...
which to you when?

I did a high level pricing taking 10 instances with Basic in Data fusion.
and 10 instance cluster (n1-standard-8) in Dataflow.

The pricing is more than double for Datafusion.

What are the pros and cons for each over one another

Answer (score 8):

Cloud Dataflow is purpose built for highly parallelized graph processing. And can be used for batch processing and stream based processing. It is also built to be fully managed, obfuscating the need to manage and understand underlying resource scaling concepts e.g how to optimize shuffle performance or deal with key imbalance issues. The user/developer is responsible for building the graph via code; creating N transforms and or operations to achieve desired goal. For example: read files from storage, process each line in file, extract data from line, cast data to numeric, sum data in groups of X, write output to data lake.

Cloud Data Fusion is focused on enabling data integration scenarios => reading from source (via extensible set of connectors) and writing to targets e.g. BigQuery, storage, etc. It does have parallelization concepts, but they are not fully managed like Cloud Dataflow. CDF rides on top of Cloud Dataproc which is a managed version for Hadoop based processing. It's sweet spot is visual based graph development leveraging an extensible set of connectors and operators.

Your question is based on "cost" concepts. My advice is to take a step back and define what your processing/graph goal(s) look like. Then look at each products value. If you want full control over processing semantics with greater focus on analytics and want to run in batch and or must have streaming focus on Dataflow. If you want point and click data movement, with less focus need on data analytics AND do not need streaming then look at CDF.